# JNA - Ubuntu - XGetInputFocus

Tags: java, ubuntu, javafx, jna

OS: Ubuntu 16.04
JNA: 4.2.X
JDK: 1.8.0u111

I'm trying to get the currently focused window programmaticaly on a JavaFX application.

```
if (Platform.isLinux()) {
    final X11 x11 = X11.INSTANCE;
    final XLib xlib = XLib.INSTANCE;

    X11.Display display = x11.XOpenDisplay(null);
    X11.Window window = new X11.Window();
    Pointer pointer = Pointer.NULL;

    xlib.XGetInputFocus(display, window, pointer); // << ERROR
    X11.XTextProperty name = new X11.XTextProperty();
    x11.XGetWMName(display, window, name);
    System.out.println(name.toString());
}

public interface XLib extends StdCallLibrary {

    XLib INSTANCE = (XLib) Native.loadLibrary("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so", XLib.class);

    int XGetInputFocus(X11.Display display, X11.Window focus_return, Pointer revert_to_return);
}
```

But it doesn't work and throws this exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized calling convention: 63
at com.sun.jna.Native.invokeInt(Native Method)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:390)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:323)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:236)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.XGetInputFocus(Unknown Source)
at application.Main.start(Main.java:33)
```

Is this line correct ?

```
XLib INSTANCE = (XLib) Native.loadLibrary("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so", XLib.class);
```

---

I tested with an older version of JNA (4.1.X) and the error changed for :

```
Unrecognized calling convention: 1
```

---

Debug log with `-Djna.debug_load=true`

```
Looking in classpath from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93 for /com/sun/jna/linux-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so
Found library resource at jar:file:/home/puglic/eclipse/jna-4.2.2.jar!/com/sun/jna/linux-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so
Looking for library 'X11'
Adding paths from jna.library.path: null
Trying libX11.so
Found library 'X11' at libX11.so
Looking for library 'X11'
Adding paths from jna.library.path: null
Trying libX11.so
Found library 'X11' at libX11.so
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized calling convention: 63
```

Comment: Looks like you've got a mismatch between the JNA java code and the JNA native library being loaded.  Try running with `-Djna.nosys=true`, which ignores any system-installed versions of JNA and unpacks the one included in jna.jar.

Comment: @technomage It seems that it does not work. I added `-Djna.nosys=true` to VM args, unpacked jna.jar and load `libjnidispatch.so` via `System.load`. I got the same exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `XLib` definition uses `StdCallLibrary`, which only makes sense on 32-bit windows systems.  It should simply be `Library`, or derive from the JNA contrib-defined version.

You're basically asking for a calling convention that does not exist.

Comment: Well spotted ! Nevermind, now I got a JVM error `A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment` `C  [libX11.so.6+0x22e47]  XGetInputFocus+0x57`. Is it related to JNA ? or is it a JVM problem ?

Comment: Most likely it's due to ill-formed or incorrectly mapped arguments.  Specifically, you need a pointer to `Window` as the second argument, not a `Window`.

Comment: I believe the X11 library mapping includes a `WindowByReference` type.

Comment: I got the same error with `WindowByReference`. It seems really hard to get it works. [This example](https://github.com/hexj/training/blob/master/practice/jna_jni_practice/src/main/java/tool/activewindow/gettitle/ActiveWindowTitle.java) uses `Window` too.

Comment: From the man page, `int XGetInputFocus(Display *display, Window *focus_return, int *revert_to_return)`.  The second argument must be of pointer type.  Ask a separate question and indicate _exactly_ what you tried.  Note that `WindowByReference.getValue()` is how you retrieve the "returned" window.  You also need to pass `IntByReference` as the final argument, or you're just passing garbage to the function.

Comment: Ok ! The rest is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41804977/jna-jvm-fatal-error-xgetinputfocus-ubuntu). Thanks!